# getchar() function not reading the correct value

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

When I enter 0 the program ends. But there is `getchar()` in if statement and it doesn't work, can you help me?

On case 0 I want it to get char from user. If `'N'` or `'n'` is entered the program will end but if not the program will start over again. (from sec1).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;

    sec1:
    printf("Select a number between 4 and 0: ");
    scanf("%d[\n]", &n);

    switch(n)
    {
        case 0:
            puts("Are you sure?");
            puts("Yes(Y) or No(N)");
            if(getchar() == 'N') goto sec1;
            break;

        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            puts("Only numbers between 4 and 1 are accepted!");
            goto sec1;
            break;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

working one

```
int main()
{
    int n, c;

    sec1:
    printf("Select a number between 4 and 0: ");
    scanf("%d/n", &n);

    switch(n)
    {
        case 0:
            puts("Are you sure?");
            puts("Yes(Y) or No(N)");
            fflush(stdin);
            if (getchar() == 'N') goto sec1;
            break;

        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            puts("Only numbers between 4 and 1 are accepted!");
            goto sec1;
            break;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using a `goto`? Just use a loop.

Comment: Hint: Does it behave differently if you press 'N' or 'n'?

Comment: actually condition was if(getchar()=='N' || getchar()=='n') but i couldnt do it

Comment: @user2588276: If that's the actual condition, why are you showing us something different? Show us real code. It doesn't work because there are two calls to `getchar()`. If you're going to look at the result of `getchar()` more than once, assign it to a variable and look at the variable: `int c; c = getchar(); if (c == 'N' || c == 'n') ...`

Comment: i said it was*
edit:also its not working with the way you said it still ends without asking user char

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very good problem description. Tell what output or result you get, and what is expected or wanted output or result, how does it not work... Though I have to add, your code snippet is very good: complete yet short, and properly formatted and indented too :)

Comment: expected result is if user enters 0 it will ask yes or no, and if user enter Y it will end.If user enter N it will return to beginning(sec1)-problem is when user enters 0 it ends without asking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d[\n]",&n);
```

to

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

The reason that your original code does not work is because scanf wants to read an integer, a "[", a "\n" and a "]". So when you input an integer followed by a "\n", scanf only takes the integer(because it expects to see a "["). Then the getchar will simply take the remaining "\n". That's why your getchar() seems not working.

Hope it is helpful to you!

Comment: thank you that solved problem.wonder why mine didnt work.i wrote it to avoid newline chachter with scanf.Anyway thanks

Comment: the problem is newline chachter with scanf.This one works to avoid it however puts are shown after second input taken, really confusing

Comment: Hi all. Thanks! I added some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some symbols in the input buffer when you are reading "N" or "n". You need to flush an input buffer before new reading. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) for details.

Briefly just write:
`while (getchar() != '\n') {}`
right after `scanf(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the terminal which is in cooked mode, thereby only feeding typed characters to the program when the user completes a line by hitting return. You can test it by feeding it input from a pipe instead of interactively from the terminal.